# Convert nested list of dicts to flat list of dicts

Tags: python

How do I convert this dictionary structure

```
[
    { 'city': 'Fake City', 'streets': {'Fake Street', 'Fake Way'}},
    { 'city': 'Ocean City', 'streets': {'Ocean Street', 'Ocean Way'}},
    { 'city': 'Forest City', 'streets': {'Forest Street', 'Forest Way'}},
]
```

into this one?

```
[
    { 'city': 'Fake City', 'street': 'Fake Street'},
    { 'city': 'Fake City', 'street': 'Fake Way'},
    { 'city': 'Ocean City', 'street': 'Ocean Street'},
    { 'city': 'Ocean City', 'street': 'Ocean Way'},
    { 'city': 'Forest City', 'street': 'Forest Street'},
    { 'city': 'Forest City', 'street': 'Forest Way'}
]
```

Sorry for the generic title. Perhaps I'm just missing the correct term.

I could try to loop of the items. A built in function or library for that would be nice.

Comment: *Did* you try a loop? What happened? Give a [mre].

Comment: I agree with @jonrsharpe in that a loop looks like the obvious choice, but if you haven't attempted it, it falls under https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Any library that would do this kind of thing automatically would be far harder to learn how to use than a specific loop construct you do to create the records you need.

Comment: _I could try to loop of the items._ You should. This seems rather straightforward, so what is the issue, exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iterate all the items in street and combine with city

```
a = [
        { 'city': 'Fake City', 'streets': {'Fake Street', 'Fake Way'}},
        { 'city': 'Ocean City', 'streets': {'Ocean Street', 'Ocean Way'}},
        { 'city': 'Forest City', 'streets': {'Forest Street', 'Forest Way'}},
    ]

res = []
for item in a:
    for st in item["streets"]:
        res.append({"city": item["city"], "streets": st})

res


[{'city': 'Fake City', 'streets': 'Fake Street'},
 {'city': 'Fake City', 'streets': 'Fake Way'},
 {'city': 'Ocean City', 'streets': 'Ocean Street'},
 {'city': 'Ocean City', 'streets': 'Ocean Way'},
 {'city': 'Forest City', 'streets': 'Forest Way'},
 {'city': 'Forest City', 'streets': 'Forest Street'}]
```